# Where possible harrasment is at play is it possible to identify all past comments from a user

Tags: support, comments

Greetings fellow ELU enthusiasts!

For some many months now, it seems a particular user here, has nothing better to do with their time, than follow me around on ELU and comment whenever they get the chance on most things I say.

Their comments are mostly passive aggressive, and almost always seeking to elicit some kind of negative response from myself.

In isolation the individual comments just appear almost pointless, but there is most certainly a pattern.

I am trying to figure out if there is an easy way either for myself or a moderator, to review all the comments this person has addressed to me, or to answers I have made.

The sum total of these would I am sure show a marked degree of harassment.

The childish behavior wastes my time as I get comment notifications and can not see this particular individual has commented until I view the comment, and also serves to clutter questions with comments needlessly.

By way of research, I have checked out if there is a feature to ignore such users, and it appears there is not. I did find this [Ignore Users Script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/ignore-users-script) - an ignore users script which I will explore.

This question however relates specifically to identifying comments by this user addressed to me, or in my answers. If there is anyway to easily catalogue them, so that I can then submit them to a moderator for review.

As I say individually the comments are just obviously giving incorrect advice, or seemingly pointless, but the pattern, will almost certainly demonstrate harassment.

The main motivation for me asking this question is that I think on a point of principle if someone wants to waste their own time that is fine, but they should not be permitted to waste the time of other people who happen to be busy but enjoy fruitful questioning and answering on ELU.

Comment: Presumably, the user in question, deletes their comments?

Comment: The answer is "flag" the comments to the mods, they will usually handle these matters.

Comment: Mari-Lou is correct, though OP should also consider whether doing so would actually reveal a pattern of harassment or just oversensitivity shading into feelings of persecution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find a list of *all* of a user's (not deleted) comments at `https://english.stackexchange.com/users/####?tab=activity&sort=comments`, where `####` is their id. You can get to this by going to their profile, and clicking on these tabs: Activity > All Actions > Comments.

Moderators can see a list of a user's deleted comments (by going to [mod > info > comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134029/323179) on that user's profile).

If you want a list of only the comments that are likely addressed to you, SEDE is the tool (assuming the comments are not deleted). SEDE is only updated once per week on Sundays, so it will not have the most recent information necessarily (but I doubt it matters too much here).

I made a [simple script](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/757316?posterID=191178&commenterID=191178) that can find all the times a certain user has commented on your posts:

```
select c.Id as [Comment Link]
from Posts p
join Comments c on p.id = c.postID

where p.id = c.postID and p.owneruserid = ##posterID## and c.userid = ##commenterID##
order by p.CreationDate desc
```

You just need to have two IDs: the poster's ID (this would be your ID) and the commenter's ID. Just put them in the boxes that appear when you run the script.

---

I made [another (even simpler) script](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/757329) that you can use to check a specific user's comments for a string. In this case you could input `@Gary` to find their comments that contain an @mention to you. However, this will also return all the user's comments where other users with the same/similar name are @mentioned, for example, `@Gary's Student`. Anyway, here is the code:

```
select id as [Comment Link] 
from comments 
where userid = ##commenterid## and lower(text) like lower('%##text##%')
```

Comment: Moderators have been able to see [deleted comments on a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85442/allow-moderators-to-see-deleted-comments) for some time, and [a user's deleted comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121408/show-moderators-a-users-deleted-comments-in-their-profile) for slightly less time. Both facilities are over five years old, though.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks, edited. I knew it could be done but was too lazy to find the link.

Comment: That's excellent thanks for the time and effort, this is a great help thanks.